# How check if current date and time is after a given date and time

Tags: python, datetime

In Python:

1. How check if current date and time is after a given date and time object named "next_check"
2. Add X number of minutes to next check

Answer (score 3):

You can do both of those things with [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) (assuming you `import datetime` and `next_check` is actually a `datetime.datetime` instance):

1. `if datetime.datetime.now() > next_check`; and
2. `next_check += datetime.timedelta(minutes=X)`.

If it isn't a `datetime.datetime` instance, that module contains various functions (e.g. [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)) to make it into one.

Comment: Use `.utcnow()` or `.now(timezone.utc)` (if `next_check` is a naive datetime object; it also should be in UTC) instead of `.now()`. Depending on where `next_check` comes from, comparing it with local time (`.now()`) is either always wrong or just during DST transitions. See [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/4279).